# web servcie to return nested xml

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

Im calling am Oracle stored procedure in a web service which returns data based on one table, xml outputted as expected, all works fine.

I now have to return sub records for each record returned in the original data set, which will result in nested xml, what's the best way to go about this?
Currently I have a class representing the xml as a list and build it up as I read through the dataset.  I'm thinking if I build another class for the child nodes and insert this list when appropriate?
I've never done this before so that's the first thing that came to my head, though I assume there's probably a better way?

Comment: When I have nested objects in XML I usually have classes for each object type and either nest them by having lists of objects inside the parent objects if the children are unique, or use IDs to relate them as separate objects if the child objects are re-used

Comment: That's what I was thinking, just wanted to check it was a valid way to do it, thanks

Comment: Worked a treat - thanks